# Can't find the buttons to add and remove tag filters in LogCat

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, android-logcat

[image]

Can someone help me find the "saved filters" view that will enable to add and remove filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the button on the top right, to the left side of the down-pointing arrow.

[image]

Comment: Dont forget to select the answer!